# CSS com Font Awesome

Tags: html5, css3, font-awesome

Como substituir a imagem do exemplo CSS disponível em https://pastebin.com/Bm1k1Pjs por Font Awesome?

Segue código abaixo:

```
<blockquote style=' font: 14px/20px italic Times, serif; padding-left: 70px; padding-top: 18px; padding-bottom: 18px; padding-right: 10px; background-color: #dadada; border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; margin: 5px; background-image: url(images/openquote4.gif); background-position: middle left; background-repeat: no-repeat; text-indent: 23px;'>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ultricies nibh suscipit tincidunt pretium. Nulla diam tortor, mollis vitae risus sit amet, eleifend lobortis turpis. Curabitur volutpat erat a neque molestie, vel fermentum nulla tincidunt. Curabitur ultrices viverra augue ut mollis. Nunc pulvinar condimentum blandit. Nullam ligula erat, cursus vel elementum sit amet, mattis ut ipsum. Etiam mauris enim, ultrices quis lectus non, finibus vehicula enim. Curabitur semper sit amet elit vel cursus. Nullam mattis tortor quis justo cursus fermentum sed et est. Proin malesuada vehicula convallis.
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Adicione uma referência visual de como está o seu para que possamos reproduzir com mais precisão.

Comment: Como referencia visual, fica equivalente ao fancy quote desta url: https://css-tricks.com/examples/Blockquotes/.

No caso quero substituir a imagem por fonte awesome, de modo a inserir somente o CSS na tag.

Comment: como está na minha resposta? Basta você editar a posição e tamanho, conforme desejar

Answer (score 1):

Acho que esse é o caminho para o que você está procurando.

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';
blockquote
{
  font: 14px/20px italic Times, serif;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #dadada;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
  /*
  background-image: url(images/openquote4.gif);
  background-position: middle left; background-repeat: no-repeat;   
  */
  text-indent: 23px;
  
  
}

blockquote:before{ 
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  font-size: 3em;
  content: "\f10d";
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px; 
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<blockquote> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ultricies nibh suscipit tincidunt pretium. Nulla diam tortor, mollis vitae risus sit amet, eleifend lobortis turpis. Curabitur volutpat erat a neque molestie, vel fermentum nulla tincidunt. Curabitur ultrices viverra augue ut mollis. Nunc pulvinar condimentum blandit. Nullam ligula erat, cursus vel elementum sit amet, mattis ut ipsum. Etiam mauris enim, ultrices quis lectus non, finibus vehicula enim. Curabitur semper sit amet elit vel cursus. Nullam mattis tortor quis justo cursus fermentum sed et est. Proin malesuada vehicula convallis. </blockquote>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para isso basta você remover as propriedades:

```
background-image: url(images/openquote4.gif);
background-position: middle left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Importar o *CSS Font Awesome*

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Adicionar a tag `i` com a classe do ícone desejado:

```
<i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

**Veja funcionando:**

```css
blockquote {
  font: 14px/20px italic Times, serif;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #dadada;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 5px;
  text-indent: 23px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<blockquote>
  <i class="fa fa-quote-left fa-x3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris ultricies nibh suscipit tincidunt pretium. Nulla diam tortor, mollis vitae risus sit amet, eleifend lobortis turpis. Curabitur volutpat erat a neque molestie, vel fermentum nulla tincidunt. Curabitur ultrices viverra augue ut mollis. Nunc pulvinar condimentum blandit. Nullam ligula erat, cursus vel elementum sit amet, mattis ut ipsum. Etiam mauris enim, ultrices quis lectus non, finibus vehicula enim. Curabitur semper sit amet elit vel cursus. Nullam mattis tortor quis justo cursus fermentum sed et est. Proin malesuada vehicula convallis.
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Otímo. E como faço para inserir o fa-quote-left, através do CSS?

Comment: `content: "\f10d"; font-family: "FontAwesome";`.